# Change WooCommerce attribute table to two columns

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm very new to Wordpress/WooCommerce and I'm trying to do something I thought would have been simple.

The very basic WooCommerce Single Product page has the Product Attributes, they all appear under one big column.

[image]

Where can I actually modify the style and css for Product Page, so that I can have them in **2** columns?

[image]

I see the table is itself is generated under class "`woocommerce-product-attributes`" and "`shop_attributes`" ?

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: You can overwrite the following [template file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php) (see explanation in the template file on how to do this correctly). 
There you can adjust the html output of the table to your wishes

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, solved it by editing woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php. To make the change permanent between woocommerce updates, copy the file contents to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php.

Change:

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

to:

```
<table>
<?php foreach (array_chunk($product_attributes, 2) as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute) :{ ?>
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($product_attribute as $value) :{ ?>
              <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $value['label'] ); ?></th>
              <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $value['value'] ); ?></td>
    <?php } endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php } endforeach; ?>
</table>
```